# Configuring ELB to redirecting Internet Explorer traffic to a specific page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, internet-explorer

I want to redirect Internet explorer to a specific page, which says: "IE not supported"

I have configured the following rule in my Application Load Balancer to check the Browser header and if equals to "IE" or "InternetExplorer" I would permanently redirect them to the "IE not supported" page...
however this is not working...

[image]

However this is not working... I am not sure

---

An alternative solution would be to check if User-Agent header contains "Trident" or "MSIE" but I am not sure how to configure a rule to check if value `contains` a give string? I can only use `is` condition.

Comment: The problem was that CloudFront was not forwarding `User-Agent` header... After whitelisting `User-Agent` header in CloudFront, the values are coming through

Answer (score 0):

The request header you want to inspect is "User-Agent", not "Browser".

You also need to test if it contains the value, not equals. A list of IE UA's are located here: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/internet-explorer

Comment: Thanks for your answer... The problem is IE is associated with so many different values... In the screenshot that I have posted I can only use `is` condition... I don't know how to use the 'contains' condition